# Adding an attribute to a ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a `HandlerInterceptor` that needs to insert a certain session-scoped bean into the `Model`. `postHandle`'s signature looks like this:

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
```

`ModelAndView` has no `addAttribute` function. How can I add an attribute to a `ModelAndView` so that I can access it with `request.getAttribute` inside my views?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`modelAndView.addObject("key", value)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

There are also some other indirect ways, through `modelAndView.getModel()` or `modelAndView.getModelMap()`. But you should prefer the `addObject(..)` version. In fact it invokes `getModelMap().addAttribute(..)`