# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'categorie' available as request attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I'm new to Spring MVC and I have an error with a form validation and I don't know why.

I looked almost all answers related this problem on the web but could not figure out the problem in my code.

Here is my JSP page.

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <f:form method="POST" commandName="categorie" enctype="multipart/form-data"
       action="categorie/add" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
       <%-- <f:form action="addcategorie" method="post">   --%> 
      <p><label for="nomcategorie">Nom catégorie  </label><f:input type="text" id="nomcatg" path="nomcategorie"/></p>
      <p><label for="typecategorie">Type catégorie </label><f:input type="text" id="typecatg" path="typecategorie"/></p>
       <div class="pure-control-group">
              <label for="image">Image</label>  

             <%--  <c:if test="${famille.idfamille!=null}">
                             <c:if test="${famille.image!=null}">
                            <img alt="" src="photofamille?idfam=${famille.idfamille }" class="img">
                            </c:if>
                        </c:if>  --%>
                <!-- <br>
                    <br>     -->
         <input type="file" name="file" >  
          </div>
          <br>

      <div class="pure-control-group">
               <label for="couleurfond">Couleur de Fond</label>

             <f:input type="color" name="your favourite color" pattern="#[a-f0-9]{9}" value="#fad345" list="" path="couleur"/>
              <!--  Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567"> -->
               </div>
         <f:input path="idcategorie" type="text" />
      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
      </div>
   </f:form>
```

my controller:

```
@Controller
public class CategorieController {
    @Autowired
    CategorieService categorieService;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String liste(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {

//          model.addAttribute("article", new Article());

            model.addAttribute("categories", categorieService.listCategories());

             return "listCategories";
        }

     @RequestMapping(value= "/categorie/add",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="content-type=multipart/*")
      public String addFamille(@ModelAttribute("categorie") Categorie c,BindingResult bindingResult, Model model,MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
         model.addAttribute("categorie", new Categorie()); 



       if(c.getIdcategorie() == null){




          categorieService.addCategorie(c);
       }


       return "redirect:/categories";

   }

}
```

i found this error :

```
RAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'categorie' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listCategories_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f0(listCategories_jsp.java:757)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listCategories_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(listCategories_jsp.java:683)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listCategories_jsp._jspService(listCategories_jsp.java:538)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

févr. 08, 2016 2:57:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/elolink] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/listCategories.jsp at line 417

414:       <f:form method="POST" commandName="categorie" enctype="multipart/form-data"
415:        action="categorie/add" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
416:        <%-- <f:form action="addcategorie" method="post">   --%> 
417:       <p><label for="nomcategorie">Nom cat�gorie  </label><f:input type="text" id="nomcatg" path="nomcategorie"/></p>
418:       <p><label for="typecategorie">Type cat�gorie </label><f:input type="text" id="typecatg" path="typecategorie"/></p>
419:        <div class="pure-control-group">
420:               <label for="image">Image</label>
```

what's the problem ,please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP is looking for a binding bean called `categorie.`  You can add a new bean to your form in your `liste` method.

That is, move this line to your GET method:

`model.addAttribute("categorie", new Categorie());`

Then, make sure all the properties on the page are also found in your `Categorie` bean.

Also, the newer way to do this is to use `modelAttribute` instead of `commandName`.

You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025888/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-exception) for a similar situation.